# java, help using HM(hashmap)& improve efficiency. with given array with given numbers to place repetitive & non repetitive numbers in the HM correctly

Tags: java, arrays, function, hashmap

with a given array which is full of numbers and already made emptied HM, how can I enter all the values from the array to the HM (hashmap) and numbers which are repeated add to the value(starts on 1 if the number is not already in the HM ) of the same key(which is the number). I already wrote a function to do this but it doesn't seem to work.
here's my code:

```
public static void placeInHM(int[] array,HashMap<Integer, Integer> t ) {
        for(int i: array) {
            if(t.containsKey(i)) {
                t.replace(i,t.get(i)+1);
            }
            else {
                t.put(i, 1);
            }
            System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

help would be appreciated
example- array is: `[2, 3, 5, 3, 7, 9, 5, 3, 7]`
HM should be something like this, value is amount of times the same number is repeated): `[3(key),3(value)][2,1][5,2][7,2][9,1]`

Comment: Since you are using enhanced for loop, you should change `array[i]` to `i` in all places. `i` is an array element, not an array index.

Comment: it still doesn't work. ill update the code here at least then. thanks!

Comment: when you say it doesn't work, you should elaborate. Does the code pass compilation? Does it throw an exception? Does is produce incorrect output?

Comment: Just put your code in a small test program, and it's fine
 Map<Integer,Integer> tespMap = new HashMap<>();
 int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,6,5,3,4,2,1,2,3,5,7,6,4,2,1};
 placeInHM(arr,tespMap);

{1=3, 2=4, 3=3, 4=3, 5=2, 6=2, 7=1}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to print the map in the for a loop.
If you want to print only once just print outside the loop.

Moreover, you can also use getOrDefault

```
   for(int i: array) {
     t.put(i, t.getOrDefault(i,0)+1);  
}
```